# Exception while trying to save Hibernate entity without autogenerated Id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two entities, which I want to save into the database, Payment, and PaymentItem.  A Payment can have more PaymentItems.

The main entity:

```
@Entity(name = "payment")
public class PaymentEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull   // if I remove this... interesting things happen
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    private List<PaymentItemEntity> items;

    // getters, setters
}
```

The second entity:

```
 @Entity(name = "payment_item")
 public class PaymentItemEntity {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      private String code;
 }
```

So, I populate a Payment, with 1 PaymentItem, and try to save it. 
Please notice that Payment doesn't have an autogenerated id, I get the ID from somewhere else and I set it manually.

Now, what happens is that when I try to save it, Hibernate goes to the database to see if an existing entry is there along with its items (it isn't, the db is empty).

I know this because I turned on hibernate debug logging and I see:

```
2018-06-22 14:34:33.939 DEBUG 3915 --- [nio-8100-exec-2] o.h.e.i.DefaultMergeEventListener        : EntityCopyObserver strategy: disallow
2018-06-22 14:34:33.940 DEBUG 3915 --- [nio-8100-exec-2] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Loading entity: [ro.vdin.entity.PaymentEntity#60587d84-3ae6-3f1e-b63e-fa8b6658d669]
```

And then it fails with the exception:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [ro.vdin.entity.PaymentEntity] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=items, rootBeanClass=class ro.vdin.entity.PaymentEntity, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
```

Even though my initial Payment entity has a list of 1 items (hence, it's not null).

What's interesting is that if I remove the @NotNull annotation, everything is saved to the db - the Payment, the PaymentItem, and the relations between them (Hibernate creates an association table which is properly populated).

(Basically it seems that because the id of the entity is set, hibernate tries to merge it instead of saving it to the db.)

What can I do in order to keep the @NotNull annotation on List items?
And, can I do something so that it doesn't load anything from the db, and saves directly?

Comment: @NotNull is a Bean Validation annotation. It has nothing to do with database constraints itself. @Column(nullable = false) is the JPA way of declaring a column to be not-null. Why do you want to keep @NotNull??

Comment: @canillas: I want to make sure that when I save the Payment, that it has at least 1 PaymentItem.

Comment: Reagrdless of any other errors, I think the validation you would want to check at least 1 item is in the list would be `@NotEmpty` or (`@Size(min=1)` in older versions of the validation API).

Answer (score 0):

you haven't passed join column @joinColumn for example.

```
@Entity(name = "payment")
public class PaymentEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private UUID id;
@NotNull   
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Valid
private List<PaymentItemEntity> items;
// getters, setters
}
 //Child Class
@Entity(name = "payment_item")
public class PaymentItemEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String code;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")// for Example i have passed id you have pass join column name
  private PaymentEntity paymentEntity;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Comment: I haven't passed @JoinColumn, or @ManyToOne;  I want to have separate table for holding the association payment -> items.

Comment: for example 
payment table has primary key an child table using the same key(or different name) as the foreign key. that you say one too many relationships.